# sqlite_step(statment) .returns 100

Tags: iphone, sqlite

am trying to access sqlite database 
the sqlite3_step should return 0 ?? but it does not !!

```
if(sqlite3_open([DatabasePath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK){
    self.searchtext.text=DatabasePath ;

    const char *sql="select *from cars";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstatment;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql,-1,&selectstatment,Nil)==SQLITE_OK){
        self.searchtext.text=@" database prepared";

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstatment)==SQLITE_OK){
            // fetch the id
            SQLITETEST10000AppDelegate *carobject=[[SQLITETEST10000AppDelegate alloc] init ];
             carobject->primarykey=sqlite3_column_int(selectstatment, 0);
            //fetch the name
             carobject.carname =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_int(selectstatment, 1)];

            [appdelegate.Cars addObject:carobject];

            [carobject release];   
        }
    }else self.searchtext.text=@" database Not prepared";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [read the sqlite3 C API documentation (this page for `sqlite3_step` function)](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)

`sqlite3_step` can return multple values, the most common when everything is ok are `SQLITE_ROW` to tell that it successfully returned a row and `SQLITE_DONE` when it has finished iterating all rows returned by the query. `sqlite3_step` never returns `SQLITE_OK`.

A value of 100 (see [the result codes page in the doc too](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)) corresponds to `SQLITE_ROW` so this is totally what is expected in your case.